# How to make a step in pentaho transformation runs twice or more in a day?

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have 1 transformation that contains multiple steps. I want to run one of them twice in a day (every 12 hours). Any idea to make it?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the transformation in a job and run into from the command line using Kitchen. Once you get the command right, you can schedule it in cron (Linux) or the Task Scheduler (Windows).

If you want the transformation to run without a job, you can use Pan instead of Kitchen.